# Auto Exporting data from a custom field in Asana

Tags: asana, asana-api

I am looking for a way to be able to select a custom drop down field within Asana and have it automatically export a .json file of the task.  Is there any way to do this automatically? Or would I have to pull the data out through the API from outside the UI?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that nativaly in Asana. Maybe you can do this with Zapier, but I am not even sure they can detect a custom field change. Same for the API, you'll have to check if there are webhooks for custom field change. If not, you can build a Chrome extension that does that.

Comment: ok, thanks for the reply.  I thought I might have to go another way with this.